# How to annotate a request body that is oneOf external models?

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi

I'm working on documenting an API made with RESTeasy + Jackson in Java using Swagger/OpenAPI (version 1.5.18 - I did add in v3 OAS 2.0.1 to try oneOf/anyOf). One of the endpoints takes in a `String` as a request body, which is then transformed into one of several classes. The documentation needs to display each of these models so that users can see them. The models are defined in another project. Is there a way to do this through annotations? The closest thing I've found is adding `@RequestBody(content=@Content(schema=@Schema(oneOf= {class1.class, class2.class})))` but haven't been able to get it to add the model using that. I also tried adding a dummy class with `@ApiModel(subTypes={class1.class, class2.class}`. I don't want to add additional endpoints for each object type due to code maintainability.

My question is: is it possible to add the models through annotations while leaving the input type as `String`?

Here is the relevant code:

```
@POST
@Path("/{filetype}/new")
@Consumes("application/json")   
public Response writeFile(
    @ApiParam(required=true, allowableValues = "class1, class2") @PathParam("filetype") String filetype, 
    @RequestBody(content=@Content(schema=@Schema(oneOf= {class1.class, class2.class}))) String inputFile
    ) {
        return validateFileAndSaveToServer(filetype, inputFile);
}
```

Comment: Same issue, did you manage to solve it?